# Ignore header/comments reading CSV with array_map() and str_getcsv() as the callback

Tags: php, arrays, csv-import

Is there a method to ignore header/comments when using the following PHP method combination:

`$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));`

**Example CSV**

```
date, val1, val2, val3
2014-12-2, 1, 4, 5 
2014-12-3, 2, 1, 3 
2014-12-4, 2, 0, 1
```

I'd like `$csv[0][0]` to equal `2014-12-2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_shift :

```
array_shift($csv);
```

Comment: Thanks! according to the [array_shift docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php), this would assign the `$csv` variable the header row array, right?

Comment: Just use array_shift($csv);